# NSTextField string with newlines

Tags: swift, nstextfield

I have a series of objects with an optional "comment" field, which contains a string. I'd like to extract all the comments and list them as separate lines in an NSTextField (or any other suitable view). So I did this...

```
@IBOutlet var CommentsTextView: NSTextView!

func CommentsInitialize() {
    var cmt = ""
    for c in document!.commentCards {
        cmt += c.info["comment"] ?? "" + "\n"
    }
    CommentsTextView.string = cmt
}
```

The text appears, but as all one line run together. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889500/nstextfield-setstringvalue-append-strings-to-nstextfield) it should just work, but the newlines simply aren't doing anything (and I tried \n, \r\n and \r). Am I missing something obvious? I can see in IB that there's a setting in the TextStorage for the newline mode, but I can't seem to set it, changing the value does nothing.

p.s. If you're wondering about the missing "weak", apparently that's an old Cocoa issue - with the weak in there it released and died

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the nil coalescing operator `??` has a lower precedence (`131`) than the `+` operator (`140`), hence the line:

```
cmt += c.info["comment"] ?? "" + "\n"
```

will be evaluated as

```
cmt += c.info["comment"] ?? ("" + "\n")
```

Subsequently, line break escape character `"\n"` will be added to `cmt` only if `c.info["comment"]` contains nil.

If you replace the line with the following

```
cmt += (c.info["comment"] ?? "") + "\n"                  // (+)
```

then line breaks will be added also for cases where `c.info["comment"]` is non-nil.

---

Now, the fixed procedure `(+)` above will add line breaks also for empty (`""`) as well as nil-valued comment fields, and also one final line break after the last comment field content. If you only want to add line breaks only for actual existing comments (not `nil` neither empty), you could use `if let` optional binding rather than the nil coalescing operator:

```
if let str = c.info["comment"] where str.characters.count > 0 {
    cmt += str + "\n"
}

/* remove last trailing '\n' */
cmt.removeAtIndex(cmt.endIndex.advancedBy(-1))
```

Comment: Oh wow. I was sure this had something to do with the NSTextField, I never imagined this was to do with the string itself. Thanks dfri!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Happy to help! Just a note: it wasn't the string, per se, but rather the precedence of the operators, which is not limited to `String` instances. In this case, these happen to have implementations for `String` instances, but you would've seen the same behaviour for say, attempted unwrapping and subsequent addition of `10` to some optional `Int` (i.e., `myInt = myOptionalInt ?? 0 + 10` is equivalent to `myInt = myOptionalInt ?? (0 + 10)` <-- `10` only added if `myOptionalInt` is `nil`).